# How to create a barrier for sound waves?

Tags: waves, acoustics, laser, noise

Is there a way to create a barrier so that sound waves cannot pass through? Does laser light have this ability to act as a barrier or bounce sound waves back?

This came to my mind when I was thinking of a device that can be used to reduce or remove the noise then became curious. This question is not about inventing something or business. it's just about my curiousity in physics.
Thanks

Comment: For the first part of your question, http://www.homedepot.com/b/Building-Materials-Insulation-Acoustic-Insulation/N-5yc1vZc612

Comment: I believe that sound studios use foam to deaden sound.

Answer (score 2):

I suppose you could say this is cheating, but you could surround the object emitting the sound with a perfect vacuum. Sound waves are vibrations in a medium; because a perfect vacuum has nothing in it, it cannot "conduct" (for lack of a better word) sound waves. You could attempt to levitate the object with magnets; because of [Earnshaw's theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Earnshaw%27s_theorem), the setup would not be perfectly stable, but it should be okay for all intents and purposes.

Comment: As far as a barrier is concerned you can make a hollow wall with vacuum inside ,it will make sure that practically no sound will go through it.I guess it will be much easier than surrounding the sound source with vacuum .

Comment: thanks...I am more interested to know if sound waves can pass through a layer of laser light. Can laser really stops sound waves or it will act as another medium? With vacuum we simply remove the medium as you said but I'd like to know if there is anything like say x-ray or anything that is strong enough not to vibrate when sound waves hit it?