# Isolate an electronic drum from the ground

Tags: classical-mechanics, spring, vibrations

Please note that I know nothing about this part of physics, so sorry if I make some mistakes.

Drum is an awesome instrument, yet it can easily make your neighbours very angry.The vibrations caused by the bass pedal propagate through the floor and get amplified, and I am trying to reduce (negate ?) that structure-borne noise.

As far as I know, there are 2 cheaps ways for achieving this, yet I am wondering, and that's why I am here, which one would be the best. On both images, the drum is supposed to be on top :)

Here is the first solution: [image: Solution A]

And here is the second one : [image: Solution B]

So basically, it's a spring-mass system.

Most people I met tend to go for the solution B, probably because it is cheaper. Yet, for my neighbour's sake, I would really like to reduce the noise as much as possible. So what solution would provide the best reduction ?

Comment: Related: http://physics.stackexchange.com/questions/145630/how-to-create-a-barrier-for-sound-waves. I wouldn't consider it a duplicate, though, because this presents two specific options.

Comment: a bit off topic (sorry) but I played in a band with an awesome drummer. He did alot of practice - his dad made for him 'blank drums' to practice on. This was wodden flat surface which could be mounted as a normal drum with a piece of carpet over the top. He said that the feel of the carpet on wood was like a drum and it was very quiet when I heard him practice on it once.... ....apologies that this is a different and not very physics solution, which is wny it is in comment not answer.